# Localization in node.js with express

Tags: node.js, localization

Which package do you use for localization with express in node.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[node-localize](https://github.com/AGROSICA/node-localize) can work together with express.

Depending on where you want the localization, [jqtpl-express-i18n](http://ricardo.cc/2011/04/28/localization-on-nodejs-express-jquery-templates.html) can do the job for templating.

Answer (score 9):

Actually I use this NPM Package [i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n)

It have a very simple usage with Express framework... create locales folder (it.json, en.json, etc...)

```
// load modules at bootstrap
var app = express();
var i18n = require("i18n");

//set configuration
i18n.configure({
  locales:['en', 'de'],
  directory: __dirname + '/server/locales'
});
app.use(i18n.init);


// and then, in controller we can use response
res__('YOUR_KEY')
```

Front End side just set the HTTP header `Accept-Language` with value 'en', 'it', etc.

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2

John Resig's implementation

His blog post on it

http://ejohn.org/blog/i18n-module-for-node-and-express-js/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [language-translator](https://github.com/hkaraoglu/language-translator) library. It uses json files to load texts. You can define languages whatever you want.

- It supports parametrized requests.(that contains :parameter)
- It supports output text both of route file and view file.
- It is fully customizable.
- It uses and manage cookie to know user preference.
- It loads language file in middleware function by matching your route path and language file. No needs to require language files in every route file.
- It translates default language's json files' texts by using Yandex translate API. (Free)

Answer (score 2):

I found few of the best libraries to deal with localization in nodeJS:

1. **node-gettext** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gettext
2. **globalize** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/globalize
3. **i18n** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n

Answer (score 1):

I used [localizify](https://github.com/noveogroup-amorgunov/) library in own project, it's very light.

```
const localizify = require('localizify');

// ...

app.configure(() => {
    app.use((request, response, next) => {
        const lang = request.headers['accept-language'] || 'en';
        localize.setLocale(lang);
        next();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[node-localize](https://github.com/AGROSICA/node-localize) can work for Localization in node.js with express.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31508650)