# Internationalization (i18n) / Localization for Node.js web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, internationalization

I have a web application build using Node.js. I wish to do internationalization and support english and Spanish language.

Whenever the user selects the english link the static content of my 'index.ejs' page should be in english and when he selects Spanish it should change accordingly.

How can I do that?
What would be the simplest way to do that?
Also, How can I improve Search Engine Optimization (SEO)?

Comment: Try to use this example: https://gist.github.com/mashpie/08e5a0ee764f7b6b1355

Comment: Also you might check [this example](https://github.com/efkan/node-intl-polyfill-example) out. It explains how to implement i18n in very easy way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Localization in node.js with express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645740/localization-in-node-js-with-express)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-node

Provides simple API on the application and template level. So you need to build a dictionary and use it whereever you want.

About SEO: take a look at this article: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang. Shortcut: you need to render your language `<meta>` tags according to you current language (or the prefered one). Search Robot should not get the meta tags and the content in the different languages.